# Passing value without button into Php with ajax and codeigniter

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I want to know how I can pass the value of input textbox into php variable without button and refresh of page, because I want to pass the value into controller and model. I'm using CodeIgniter.

This is just an example.

```
     Controller.php
     class Home extends CI_Controller {

        public function main(){
         $entry_id = $this->input->post('entry_id');
        $datas['query'] = $this->model->samplemodel($entry_id);
        $this->load->view('sampleview',$datas);
        }
      }
```

.

```
     Model.php

      class Model extends CI_Model{

      public function samplemodel(entry_id){
       $this->load->database();
       $this->db->select("fullname");
       $this->db->where('entry_id',entry_id);
       $query = $this->db->get('position');     
       return $query->result();
    }
   }
```

.

```
   sampleview.php

  <input type="textbox" name="id">

 <?php
 foreach($query as $row){

   echo $row->fullname;


   }

  ?>
```

.
       Output will be...

```
    grace
    paul
    mang juan
```

Every time you change the value of input textbox the output will be change.

Comment: Use a change event on the textbox instead of a click event on a button.

Comment: you have answered it **yourself** you need an on change event or on key press or up event for that input.

Answer (score 1):

add an id to the textbox

```
 <input type="textbox" id="id">
```

send via POST by jquery after event keydown pressed

```
$('#id').keydown(function (event)
{

    if (eventer code hereent.keyCode == 13)
    {
        event.preventDefault();
        var id = $(this).val();
        $.post( "/home/main", { entry_id: id });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Give class or ID to textBox then use that id or class to target keyup event of textbox.
for eg. Textbox HTML

```
<input type="textbox" id="txtId">
```

Display area html

```
<div id='innerHTMLDiv'></div>
```

Jquery live KeyUp event

```
$('#txtId').live( 'keyup', function() {
       // ajax call to post data         
});
```

Now add your ajax call to post data in php file.

```
$('#txtId').live( 'keyup', function() {
      var id = $('#txtId').val();
      $.ajax({
        url: 'sampleview.php',
        type: "POST",
        data: {id: id},
        success: function (res) {
            try {
                $('#innerHTMLDiv').html(res);
            } catch (error) {
                $('#innerHTMLDiv').html("<b>Error in load data</b>");
            }
        }
    });             
});
```

Now get id value in your sampleview.php file as below.

```
$id = $_REQUEST['id'];
```

Get Data by query and echo it. this will display your result in your innerHTMLDiv div where you want to see the result in browser.